# Go up and down in the search results of CommandT in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

How can I traverse the list brought up by CommandT using the arrow keys, after typing in some keywords?

It used to work before, but lately I only get "A" and "B" outputted into the current file.

Comment: I am able to navigate up and down with Ctrl+N, Ctrl+P

Answer (score 0):

If this happens only in the terminal, but not in GVIM, this is probably due to a misconfiguration of the cursor keys; i.e. Vim doesn't properly detect them and instead inserts (parts of) the raw keycodes. To fix that, have a look at the [Fix arrow keys that display A B C D](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Fix_arrow_keys_that_display_A_B_C_D_on_remote_shell) article in the Vim Tips Wiki.

Comment: I already saw that page. I only get encounter when using CommandT. During normal vim usage arrow keys work as expected.

Comment: Does "normal vim usage" include insert mode?! I don't think CommandT uses anything other than default Vim input methods.